# Error when using a ListView, id attribute `android.r.id.list`  is required

Tags: android, android-listview

I have my `main.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <ListView android:id="@+id/list"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />

</LinearLayout>
```

and `row.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:padding="2dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/accept"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

My program does this(I took the example from a book):

```
public class FancyListActivity extends ListActivity {

    private TextView selection;
    private static final String[] items= {"lorem", "ipsum","dolor","sit", "amet",
        "consectetuer", "adipiscing", "elit", "morbi", "vel", "ligula", "vitae", "arcu",
        "aliquet", "mollis", "etiam", "vel", "erat", "placerat", "ante",
        "porttitor","sodales","pellentesque","augue", "purus"};
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.row);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, R.id.label, items));
        selection= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label);
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id){
        selection.setText(items[position]);
    }
}
```

But now I obtain this error:

```
Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

Why I obtain this error if I have my android:id="@+id/list"?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a ListActivity. As per instructions in the Google documentation, you *need* to specify your list in your *main.xml* file like this:

`<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
   ...`

And also, you should call `setContentView(R.layout.main);` instead of setting your Activity content to your `row.xml` file as you are doing right now!

Finally, after those changes, there will be a problem remaining with these 2 lines:

```
selection= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label);
```

...and:

```
selection.setText(items[position]);
```

Comment those out and your code will work again. As for this TextView thing, I am unsure what you were trying to achieve in the first place, but if the purpose is to somehow show the content of the selected list item in a TextView object placed on top/bottom of the list, then this TextView should be placed in your *main.xml* file.